# Is there anything wrong with this? SQLite, Unity Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

This

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT username, password" + "FROM accounts" + " WHERE username ='"+username.text+"' AND password ='"+password.text+"'";
```

Comment: I reckon you better use parameters instead of text i.e. `sqlQuery = "SELECT username, password FROM accounts WHERE username =@p0 AND password =@p1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look correct:

```
'password" + "FROM accounts'
```

Doesn't this give:

```
passwordFROM accounts
```

You need a space there ~

```
'password" + " FROM accounts'
```

Answer (score 1):

Even after you fix the syntax problems with the query, i hope this is not production code. Since this way of coding would exposure your application to  SQL injection.

Eg:
If "username" is set to anything and in the "password" field some one were to put in <'1 OR '1'='1> then the query would be constructed as follows

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT username, password " + "FROM accounts" + " WHERE username ='anything' AND password ='1' OR '1'='1'";
```

In other words it would execute as follows..

```
SELECT username, password FROM accounts WHERE username ='anything' AND password ='1' OR '1'='1'
```

which means gets all username and password from the accounts table.!!